# read textfile with file descriptor in to a pipe

Tags: c, file, file-descriptor

I am here trying to read the contents of *fileDesc* wich is a file descriptor pointing to a textfile into one end of a pipe *pipe_d[1]* one character at the time. This does correctly print the characters from the file but I believe that my *write()* tries to write the memory adress of the character to the pipe and not the character if I do like this.

```
char x;
FILE *file;
file = fdopen(fileDesc, "a+");

while((x = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
{
  printf("%c", x);

  write(pipe_d[1], &x, sizeof(x));
}
```

I would like to get the character located on &x to be written in to the pipe instead. Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Either read(), or fdopen() + {fgetc(),fgets(), fread() } BTW: the combination of O_RDWR plus O_APPEND looks suspicious. And your fd refers to a plain file, not to any kind of pipe.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. The fd is an index into a table that contains detail about the file that you have open. Passing it on a pipe to another process isn't going to give that process access to it unless they happen to share the same memory space (both ends of the pipe are in the same process)

Comment: I think they're asking if there's a way to automatically take all the data in the file they're opening, and pass it into the pipe, without manually `read`ing all the data in from the file and then `write`ing the data back out to the pipe.

Comment: Thanks all, based on what you said I have made some research about this and updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a problem with x: it's a char, it cannot contain the value EOF,
   so the line:

   ```
   while((x = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
   ```

   will always evaluate to true, making the program run forever.
   Declare x as an `int` will solve this.
2. If you wish to work on a char-by-char basis, you should also `fdopen(pipe_d[1], "w")` and use `fputc(fp, x)` to write the pipe.
3. There is no call to `pipe(pipe_d)` at this time of writing; did you issue one?
4. There is no call to `fork()`, so is there any reader of the pipe? If no, the program will block after the pipe fills up.